# Android Conncect to mySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to Android and I make an app which requires a remote database. I tried all the tutorial you can find in the net and I can't make it work. I simply want to make a log in screen. Here are the files I use:

the JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {


    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return  jObj;

    }
    }

Login.java
    public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {




    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.3:80/lamp/PHP/webservice/login.php";




    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {




        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }



    }

confing.inc.php

    <?php 

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = ""; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "webservice1"; 


    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try 
    { 


        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    } 


    ?>

login.php

    <?php


    require("config.inc.php");

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }


    $validated_info = false;


    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {

        if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }


    if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
     }   else {
       ?>
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
            Username:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            Password:<br /> 
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </form> 
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
    }

  ?>
```

when I try to run the app on a device:

> 04-24 00:52:56.800  26394-26514/com.example.mysqltest E/Buffer Error﹕ 
>   Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException 04-24
>   00:52:56.800  26394-26514/com.example.mysqltest E/JSON Parser﹕ Error
>   parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
>   04-24 00:52:56.800  26394-26514/com.example.mysqltest W/dalvikvm﹕
>   threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
>   04-24 00:52:56.800  26394-26514/com.example.mysqltest
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Comment: android has no mysql support, and you don't want to expose a database to the general internet anyways. your android code calls a web service (e.g. some php code), and that code connects to mysql on android's behalf.

Comment: Which is the secure way @Marc B?? i want to make an app which will load on a listview a list of places. Users will save delete and update places  from a list based to their own preferences.

Answer (score 0):

if you notice that the error is about parsing the response .. the response is not JSON (which is supposed to be) so it can't be parsed due that the app is crashing

> 04-24 00:52:56.800 26394-26514/com.example.mysqltest E/JSON Parser﹕
>   Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:

I checked your login.php .. it's returning html .. which is causing the problem try to delete this part

```
   <h1>Login</h1> 
<form action="login.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form> 
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

because it's makes the content-type : plain/html .. which makes up the whole problem

Also you need to add this line to the beginning of your php file beneath "< ?php "

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

also make sure you test it in browser before ..